# Using Insomnia To Make Soap Calls

Tags: soap, insomnia

I am trying to use Insomnia to make soap calls - specifically trying to get post to succeed.  I defined the URL as the end point and put the body type as XML with the SOAP contents (envelope, header, body).  I defined the user id and password in the header.  When I run I get 415 Unsupported Media Type.  I can't really paste the soap contents because of all of the URL addressing in the envelope.  I am using Insomnia to succeed in doing the REST call to get my information (for some crazy reason the gets are REST but the posts are SOAP) but can't get the insert to work.  Is there something special I need, or does Insomnia not support SOAP post transactions?  I googled and it appears in 2018 this was added.  I don't have the WSDL available.

I appreciate this is not giving lots of information so guidance on what more I may provide to get assistance will also be helpful.  Has anyone succeeded in using Insomnia to make SOAP calls?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All that was needed for me to make it work was:

- Request method: `POST`.
- Setting the `Content-Type` header to `text/xml; charset=utf-8` (`application/xml` gave me the 415 response).
- Wrapping request body in proper SOAP envelope.

You should be able to call GET on `YourHandler.asmx` to look up envelopes for requests you want to use. Envelope should look somewhat like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <foo>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Bar</Name>
      </foo>
    </HelloWorld>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Credits for the guidance and envelope sample goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609294/invoking-an-asp-net-web-service-method-via-an-http-request).

Comment: I'm not sure how standard this is, but I also had to add the `SOAPAction` header to get this to work.

Answer (score 15):

You can import the `WSDL` file, so that all methods, headers etc. will be created automatically. Click on:

1. Go to dashboard
2. Click `Create`
3. Choose `URL` (under *import from*)
4. Paste the WSDL URL and click `Fetch and Import`

As an example you can use the following URL: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl

You will get this:
[image]

---

The problem as of writing this answer is, that there are two bugs:

1. Not all WSDL URLs are getting imported correctly (e.g. this one works in SOAP UI, but not in Insomnia http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL)
2. The methods are getting imported, but they don't work

You can submit and issue on Github, so that this is getting fixed: https://github.com/Kong/insomnia

Comment: Import succeeded but new no new project, request or method was created.

Comment: @PanuHaaramo I just faced the same problem... seems like they kind fixed it (pending for release...) see this issue: https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/4034

Comment: awesome comment. Thanks a lot @sunwarri0r. 
Not yet noticed, that this kind of imports are possible

Comment: I reported another WSDL import issue: https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/7083